# How can I pass values to a python C extension module during execution?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two python extension modules written in C:

`data_read`: continuously gathers data from an external source and sends it to python, and

`sound_creator`: produces a continuous tone pitch.

I have a main python script, `main`, that computes a transform on the incoming data from `data_read`. What I want to do now is somehow communicate with the `sound_creator` module so I can alter the pitch of the tone in real-time based on my incoming data.

How can I communicate with this module during execution? I can't seem to find a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `sound_creator` module should provide a suitable function to alter the pitch. E.g. `setpitch()`. Then your Python code can call it, e.g. `sound_creator.setpitch(440)`.

Does `sound_creator` define such a function? What API functions does it currently provide?  (See `dir(sound_creator)`.) Do you know how to add such a function to a Python extension if it isn't already there?

Comment: I wrote the sound_creator extension, and it does have a change_frequency function. The problem is that when I start the playback, I can't figure out a way to call change_frequency while the program is running.

Comment: Is the problem that the `sound_creator` playback is a blocking function, which doesn't return control to the Python interpretter? I see the [multiprocessing] tag. I suggest you improve your question to describe the problem you're facing. It sounds as though there are some important details that you're not explaining, which are important to be able to provide a useful answer.